# How are self-replicating mines supposed to work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Standard replicators are able to replicate mundane materials and smaller not-too-complex machines. At one point, under the influence of a Cardassian anti-riot program, the replicators in DS9 are magically able to produce something like a self-targetting automatic phaser gun.

Normally, for more complex tasks, such as "building a powerplant" or "making major parts of a starship", very special and rare *"industrial"* replicators are needed. Apparently, an entire planet normally doesn't have more than half a dozen of these, and they are valuable enough for super secret security measures so the Maquis won't steal them (which they do anyway).

In either case, replication is the process of turning energy into matter.

In addition to their main power supply and thrust, the self-replicating mines contain a standard photon torpedo warhead, which means that they are able to release a *considerable* amount of energy (which is "gone" after the explosion) from a matter/antimatter reaction. The energy, and of course the antimatter must come from somewhere (regardless of the energy needed, can a replicator replicate antimatter at all?).

It seems improbable (if not impossible) that self-replicating mines could work at all. If you were able to replicate an energy cell containing the same amount of energy as the original one *plus* a considerable amount of matter/antimatter *plus* some other stuff, like a cloaking device then you would have the most perfect perpetuum mobile imaginable.

Comment: Matter of contention, standard replicators are only limited in size and allowed or programmed patterns. They could easily create complex machines or weapons of the appropriate size if programmed to do so. Industrial replicators are simply massive in size and capacity. Same as the industrial transporters used in the cargo rooms

Comment: As for the DS9 incident, those are cardassian replicators on a military station programmed by them to produce that weapon. The Federation frowns upon automated kill machines or weapons being replicated as a matter of policy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're ignoring the fact that each mine contains a small amount of [handwavium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum?from=Main.Handwavium). In the Trek universe, it's apparently possible to extract reasonable amounts of energy from the vacuum itself and the mass is provided to the relevant mine by its neighbours (who then use the energy they've extracted to create more mass):

> *The replicator system was designed to accommodate a swarm detonation
> of up to twenty mines and still maintain the total shell. The
> replicator was a kludge of Cardassian and Starfleet types and included
> a raw-matter supply container able to contribute enough mass to build
> one-sixty-fifth of a complete mine. Mass for any one new mine was
> transported through the replicator's subspace emitters from as many
> mines away as was necessary. In a bucket-brigade system. As
> distributed over the entire shell, enough mass was stored to replace
> over 2,500 mines.*
>
> ***In the event the mass supply dwindled below 85
> percent, the replicator sections were designed to extract particles
> from the zero-point vacuum domain to replenish the system. The
> threshold was set deliberately high because of the long lead time
> required to produce small numbers of particle pairs.*** - [DS9: Technical Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Trek-Deep-Space-Nine/dp/067101563X)

Theoretically, the Cardassians could have overwhelmed the system by continually throwing things at the minefield but in practice, the mines can operate indefinitely, replacing broken mines and recharging themselves.

Comment: Any explication on the zero point vacuum domain?

Comment: @cde - Theoretically, the vacuum of space contains a form of energy that is [inexhaustible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy). In the trek universe, this energy can be extracted using [insert vague trek technobabble here].

Comment: So they use ZedPMs? Cool

Comment: I wonder how zero-point energy corresponds to deeper subspace domains...

Comment: Zero point energy is a nice explanation. Although technology to extract such substantial amounts being readily available and so common that it can be rather easily rigged together by an engineer at some remote spacestation brings up the question why this is not the default source of energy for starbases and starships, being much less a risk than matter/antimatter or fusion reactors and needing no dilithium, nor containment field or emergency eject (though without an exploding reactor, an explicit self-destruct mechanism would have to be added...)  :-)

Comment: @Damon - The implication is that it's slow and not very efficient "*The threshold was set deliberately high because of the long lead time required to produce small numbers of particle pairs.*". It would be basically useless for a starship engine or really any other application other than a static installation.

Comment: Right, but the energy needed to create even a single 1 meter object "out of nothing" (that is, from energy) is... astronomic. At roughly 500 liters of volume, that would be anywhere from 750 to 1,000kg of mass for a mostly-metal thingie, that corresponds to energy somewhere in the 2-digit petajoule range. 15% of 2,500 mines lost is 375 such objects. That's... huge. So, if there should be _any chance_ that this might work, it must be possible to gain huge amounts of zero point energy rather quickly (maybe not instantaneously, but still "pretty fast" anyway).

Comment: Damon - Theoretically you could start a fission reaction by dropping one rock on another rock, and would have to pick up and move the first rock to stop it.  But fusion reactors always require complex machinery running and a lot of energy to make atoms fuse.  One a fusion reactor produces more energy than it consumes, it can provide the energy to keep working by using some of the energy it produces,  Even them a simple switch can switch the energy to continue fusing into the energy output and the reaction will instantly shut down.  A runaway fusion reactor is impossible.

Comment: Damon - Don't say that runaway, dangerous fusion reactors are possible in Star Trek and other sci-fi shows  merely because they are seen in various episodes and are canon.  I say that dangerous runaway fusion reactors are not possible in Star Trek until someone creates a plausible theory making them 1) scientifically possible 2) technologically plausible and 3) reasonable to build, despite the difficulty in making atoms fuse at all and the obvious undesirability of fusion reactors which can runaway and explode.

Answer (score 0):

Replicators have been described a number of times to convert energy into matter.
They don't need matter to replicate things at all, only energy... however, they can decompose matter into energy which can be stored for later use (when recycling is used).

As for the self-replicating mines... you might be forgetting one source of power the mines could use.
Solar.

Keep in mind that Solar radiation is about 22 higher in space than it is on Earth.
Furthermore, the sun is emitting an enormous amounts of power... ours has an output of 380 Yottawatts.

Now, keeping in mind that technology would evolve at faster than exponential pace in real life, let alone the Trek universe... the Federation would be able to have ridiculously efficient/powerful solar energy conversion technology which would be more than enough to power replicators.

And, arguably, it would be more efficient to use self-replicating mines that for example have a hull capable of using massive amounts of solar energy for replication and regular operations.

The mines were set inside a Bajoran solar system.
Also, accumulation of power from surrounding space (background radiation) could have been used (as well as debris from older miner... though antimatter explosions would likely leave none behind - so perhaps the leftover mines might harvest the explosive energy from destroyed ones).

Bussard collectors on Federation ships were initially described as devices that generate necessary energy for the starship itself as its traveling through space - self-sufficient systems which would effectively negate the need for any kind of 'refueling' nonsense (in reality, each Federation ship has the needed technology to run indefinitely without refueling since it should be capable of replenishing its stores continuously on the go).